# access form update multiple fields

Tags: forms, ms-access, field

I'm using a form to update my table using ms access 2002, when I exit a field I would like access to duplicate the data to another field. For example, after typing address1 I would like the data to replicate to field address2. Saving time when most records have the same address in both fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you run your code if the record is new, and ask if it is not. It is usually a good idea to rename controls on forms to ensure you are referring to the control, not the field, because by default, MS Access assigns the name of the field to the control.

```
Private Sub MyTextbox_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.NewRecord Then
        Me.OtherTextbox = Me.MyTextbox
    Else
        If MsgBox("Copy this?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            Me.OtherTextbox = Me.MyTextbox
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```